# Generalization of a relation between a triangle's side lengths

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, plane-geometry

One can show that a triangle can be divided into 2 isosceles triangles if and only if the smallest angle is < 45° and is exactly one half or one third of one of the other angles, or if one of the angles is 90°. (See e.g. http://tmcs.math.unideb.hu/load_doc.php?p=41&t=doc)
The first case shows up in problem 1 of the 1992 INMO:

> In a triangle ABC, ∠A=2⋅∠B. Prove that a^2=b(b+c).

Of course, a similar relation holds in case 3. With the help of the law of sines, one also finds such a relation in case 2: (See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2426h1027827_a2b_with_minimum_perimeter)

> In a triangle ABC, ∠A=3⋅∠B. Then  (a+b)(a-b)^2=bc^2

Now I wonder: All triangles sit in one great family. Is there a general relation between their side lengths a,b,c that specializes to the above relations?

Comment: I was able to obtain additional references that shed some further light on this:
Parris, R. (2007). Commensurable triangles. The College Mathematics Journal, 38(5), 345-355.
Parris studies triangles in which one angle is k times as large as another (k-commensurable triangles) and shows that every rational k-commensurable triangle can be derived by enlarging a rational (k − 1)-commensurable triangle.

Comment: Parris  states that there exists a polynomial describing the relation between the sides of the triangle when α= r β for rational positive r and asks for an explicit formula for the aforementioned polynomial. This is provided even for real positive r by:
LEMARIE-JOHANSEN, M.. (2021). RELATION BETWEEN SIDES OF A TRIANGLE WHEN α= rβ. International Journal of Geometry, 10(2).